# Problems positioning tables or sections within a div

Tags: html, css

I hope someone might be able to help. I have a div id="main" with a blue background and a width of 100%. When I try to put a table or a section within the div, they end up overflowing off of the blue background even though I place the closing tag after the table or section. The blue background is not expanding to fit the new content, it is ignoring the table or section.

Comment: Can you please add a live example of your code?

Comment: Most probably a `floating` issue. Need to see the HTML and CSS to give you an answer. Always, always provide some code.

Comment: Are you experiencing the same problem described here - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-3?

Comment: I think you should add overflow css property for background color, also try z-index for color.

Comment: I will add HTML and CSS

Comment: I figured it out! I had an extra </div> and it screwed up the whole page. I don't know why that happened.